# Schedule a job every hour between 50 and 60 minutes once

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to use @Schedule in spring with and I would like to know if there is an option to use cron to run every hour once between minute 50 and 59, for example:
it will run: 13:58, 14:52, 15:57 16:50 etc...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

See this example:

```
0 50-59/1 * * *
```

From the crontab man page, section 5:

```
       field         allowed values
       -----         --------------
       minute        0-59
       hour          0-23
       day of month  1-31
       month         1-12 (or names, see below)
       day of week   0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)

 A field may be an asterisk (*), which always stands for ``first-last''.

 Ranges of numbers are allowed.  Ranges are two numbers separated with a hyphen.  The specified range is inclusive.  For example, 8-11 for an
 ``hours'' entry specifies execution at hours 8, 9, 10 and 11.

 Lists are allowed.  A list is a set of numbers (or ranges) separated by commas.  Examples: ``1,2,5,9'', ``0-4,8-12''.
```

Comment: nope this will run every minute between 50-59 with the following logic:
13:50, 13:51, 13:52, 13:53, 13:54, 13:55 ...

Comment: i am not sure cron formatting can be implemented to be random.

Comment: yep, me neither. that's what I'm trying to find out

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
0 55 * 1/1 * ? *
```

[cronmaker.com](http://www.cronmaker.com/) always was a good resource to me for generating cron expressions.

I think `@Scheduled` only accepts static cron expressions and you must not use SpEL in the expression.

You can however implement a custom [`Trigger`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/Trigger.html). Together with the to be executed task, this trigger can be registered by implementing [`SchedulingConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfigurer.html) in your `@Configuration` class using [`ScheduledTaskRegistrar.addTriggerTask`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTaskRegistrar.html#addTriggerTask-java.lang.Runnable-org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger-).

Comment: the expression you wrote will trigger every hour at minute 55, it's not what i'm looking for

Comment: @GalSosin, see my edits regarding `SchedulingConfigurer`

Comment: @GalSosin did you try to use `SchedulingConfigurer` or did you make any other progress on this question?

Comment: didn't try that

Comment: @GalSosin did you try implementing `SchedulingConfigurer` in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **RandomValuePropertySource** from Spring

Try it:

```
@Scheduled(cron='0 ${random.int[0,9]} * 1/1 * *')
```